# Playing a local file on RPi with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I have a Raspberry Pi set up with a Node.js app that responds when it sees button push from an Amazon Dash Button. It was originally supposed to be a silent doorbell from https://github.com/initialstate/silent-doorbell, but I would like to just have it play a local sound file. Which I think should be easy enough, but my inexperience with coding leaves me just trying new stuff that I find all over the internet.

I can play the file from the terminal with the following and it plays just fine:

```
$ omxplayer example.mp3
```

But, no matter how I try to put it in the Node.js app and trigger when the Dash Button is pressed it won't work.

```
var dash_button = require('node-dash-button'),
    dash = dash_button('XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'), //REPLACE WITH YOUR ADDRESS
    exec = require('child_process').exec;
    Omx = require('node-omxplayer');
    player = Omx('~/node_modules/node-dash-button/example.mp3');

let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

dash.on('detected', function() {
    console.log('Button pushed!');
    player.play();
});
```

When run with my latest as above, I get this:

```
/home/pi/node_modules/node-dash-button/doorbell.js:7
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

After upgrading Node.js to the newest version as suggested by @Quentin using the Major Version Upgrade directions on this site http://thisdavej.com/upgrading-to-more-recent-versions-of-node-js-on-the-raspberry-pi/ I was able to get past this. Now I can't get past how to properly use omxplayer. When running the same code as above after the Node.js upgrade I now get this error after pressing the Amazon Dash button which then crashes the app:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/node_modules/node-dash-button $ sudo node doorbell.js 
Button pushed!
/home/pi/node_modules/node-omxplayer/index.js:103
                        throw new Error('Player is closed.');
                        ^

Error: Player is closed.
    at writeStdin (/home/pi/node_modules/node-omxplayer/index.js:103:10)
    at EventEmitter.Omx.omxplayer.play (/home/pi/node_modules/node-omxplayer/index.js:133:27)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/node-dash-button/doorbell.js:13:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at PcapSession.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/node-dash-button/index.js:87:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at PcapSession.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at PcapSession.on_packet_ready (/home/pi/node_modules/node-dash-button/node_modules/pcap/pcap.js:99:10)
    at packet_ready (/home/pi/node_modules/node-dash-button/node_modules/pcap/pcap.js:44:14)
```

I tried a few different things to try and get the player to spawn with no luck. The index.js file referenced mentions to use the player.running command but I still get the player is closed error when attempting to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of Node older than the 4.x series.

Consequently it sees `let` as an identifier rather than the keyword, so it doesn't expect it to be immediately followed by another identifier (`spawn`).

Upgrade your installation of Node to a current version.

---

Alternatively, use a different variable declaration, such as `var`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks. I had thought that I was on the latest version available for Raspberry Pi. After a little research I realized I had to force it. So using this site http://thisdavej.com/upgrading-to-more-recent-versions-of-node-js-on-the-raspberry-pi/ under the Major Version Upgrade I was able to get up to the newest version. After that I had to rebuild and my current issue is solved. Now onto why omxplayer is throwing "Error: Player is closed."